# Yii createCommand not working

Tags: yii

I use Yii MVC to develop code, and I have a code, that does not work;

I can't find the error, maybe you guys can;

```
$sql = "
            select extension
            from file_extension
            where status = :status and extension in ('" . $extensions . "');
            ";
```

`$status = FileExtension::ACTIVE_STATUS;
        $cmd = Yii::app()->getDb()->createCommand($sql);
        $cmd->bindParam(":status", $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $arrObj = $cmd->queryAll();`

when I use `print_r($arrObj);` i get `array()`

Why don't I get results?

after some work, I see that my query is like:

select extension
`from file_extension
            where status = :status and extension in ('gif
      ','pdf
      ','chm
      ');`

and because of the line breakes and the empty spaces, my sql query fails;

what can i do to obtain:

select extension
`from file_extension
            where status = :status and extension in ('gif','pdf','chm');`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you are getting?

Comment: Try: Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);

Comment: the same thing happens

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian is the issue that your extensions in the generated query have a trailing space?

Comment: i cant see any trailing space; but it's there, and how can i fix it?

Comment: Also paste your $sql in the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a simple typo and has no value for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$extensionList = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('extension')
            ->from('file_extension AS fe')
            ->where("fe.status = :status AND fe.extension IN ('gif','pdf','chm')", array(':status' => FileExtension::ACTIVE_STATUS))
            ->queryAll();
```

Comment: this is how i spotted the trail space; so, yes, it gaved me the solution